I couldn't write data while using flutter blue plus
In my Flutter project, I am using the blue_plus package to connect to a device via Bluetooth. After connecting to the device, I can perform read operations, but first, I need to send a "start command" to the device to make it start producing data. I am sending the start command in decimal (or ASCII) format, but I can't read any data afterwards. I am sure that the command is correct, but maybe I am doing the conversion wrong? I don't have much information about the write method of the blue_plus library and I would appreciate your help.
Here is my code (just required parts):
List<BluetoothService> blServices = await _connectedDevice!.discoverServices();

  
    List<String> serviceData = [];
    List<String> characteristicData = [];

  
    List<int> startScanCodeBytes = [
      40, 83, 84, 82, 41, 40, 76, 83, 41, 49, 40, 92, 76, 83, 41, 40, 69, 78, 68, 41, 114, 110
    ];
  


    for (BluetoothService service in blServices) {
      serviceData.add(service.toString());
      List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics = service.characteristics;
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
        if (c.properties.read) {
          List<int> value = await c.read();
          characteristicData.add(value.toString());
        }
        if (c.properties.write) {
          await c.write(startScanCodeBytes);
        
         
          if (c.properties.read) {
            List<int> newValue = await c.read();
            print('response: ${String.fromCharCodes(newValue)}');
          } 
         else {
          print("wrong data");
         }
        }
      }
    }

The list you see in the code is the converted form of my ASCII command. As I mentioned, I am not getting any response with this list. I also tried it in its decimal form, but nothing changed.
